# Recursively increment char string value in C

Tags: c, recursion, brute-force

I'd like to implement a brute force password cracker using pthreads. In order to generate a password, I'd like to generate a string like so:

```
a
b
c
..
z
aa
ab
..
zz
..
aaa
aab
...
zzz
```

My idea is to use a recursive function that will generate a char one by one like in the example above. Heres what I've coded so far for the function:

**Generator :**

```
void generator(char * pwd, int index) {

    char alphabet[] =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ0123456789!~*";


    while(index < PW_SIZE) {

        pwd[0] = alphabet[index];
        printf("%s\n",pwd);

        generator(pwd, index+1);

    }

    if(index == PW_SIZE)
        return;
}
```

**In pthread, I call generator like this :**

```
char* pwd = malloc(PW_SIZE * sizeof(char));
//memset(pwd, 'a', PW_SIZE);
generator(pwd, 0);
```

I know that I shouldn't put pwd[0] otherwise it'll only change the first cell but this was just for testing. The pwd in the @params comes from a char * pwd that I declared in the pthread. (malloc sizeof password lenght).

I know that it isnt a good idea to declare the alphabet in the generator function, ill move that to the thread as well once this is sorted out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @skrrgwasme my question is what am I doing wrong in the function?

Comment: Why don;t use ASCII values representations and operate on them?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. How do you call `generator`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh as in : for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) ? Something like that?

Comment: @JohnLivingston Right you are, saves you the headache of writing and maintaining the whole _array initalizer_.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I call it like so: generator(pwd, 0); and pwd is : char* pwd = malloc(PW_SIZE * sizeof(char));

Comment: @JohnLivingston put that into the question.

Comment: @JohnLivingston the algorithm is just plain wrong. It's time now to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: what goes wrong? Did u try stepping through using a debugger

Comment: @MichaelWalz I edited the question. What debugger do you suggest? Im currently coding in gedit and compiling in terminal...

Comment: @pm100 well it only prints out the letter 'h' infinitely. I'd like for it to reach the end of the alphabet, then move to the next cell and do the same for a, then b and so on..

Comment: @JohnLivingston Use GDB (possibly with the -tui flag). In the meantime, you need to give us more information. What goes wrong? What happens when you execute this code? Does it compile? Errors? Segfaults? You haven't told us anything about what goes wrong. You should edit your description of the behavior into the question itself, and describe how it differs from what you expected.

Comment: @JohnLivingston hint: dont bother using threads before `generator` doesn't work properly.

Comment: that while loop will never exit, its local copy of index never varies

Comment: @SouravGhosh, using an array is better IMO. Some websites have a limited set of characters that they allow for password. So, having a whitelist makes things faster and easier to maintain in such cases. e.g. If a website has password only made up of numbers, you can speed up the code by reducing the whitelist array to just numbers. In that case, only configurable parameter becomes the array. The code logic stays the same.

Comment: I'm compiling it with -Wall at the moment and no errors at compilation. The problem I'm having is that it either only prints out "AAAAAA" or it infinitely prints out only 1 letter without moving to the next one in the dictionary. I didn't think it would be so difficult but I just can't wrap my head around it. Sorry if the question wasn't very clear.

Comment: @anishsane while that is a very welcome solution, I'd love to stick to different functions for uppercase, lowercase, numeric and remaining-alpha to have a easy mix up of all possible combinations. Just saying'. :)

Comment: Perhaps re-visualizing the problem might help.  Think of the possible passwords as a tree, with each node have N lower levels, with N being the number of characters in your alphabet.  (so the root represents an empty password, and its children are N single character passwords, etc) Then get some basic concepts from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal.  Most likely you'd like to traverse the tree by level